# While loop throwing Notice of Undefined on using new index for array

Tags: php, arrays

I have three different arrays. Getting the value from first array and measuring it in second array if match found enter that data into new array, 1st array is **types**, 2nd array is **results** and 3rd array is **data**. Problem occurs when I use `$data[$types[$i]]['price'] += $result[$x]['price'];` it throws notice error

> NOTICE Undefined index: price on line number 28

If I use it in a way like `$data[$types[$i]][] = $result[$x]['price'];`

> this generates new index array but does not plus the price and does not show the Notice as well.

The question is if it does not accept the price as an index then why it accept `$data_array[$types[$i]]['name']` name as index in row before it. And I want to plus all the prices and assign it to the key **price** and of course want to get rid of notice.

```
$types[] = "class";
$types[] = "late_fine";
$types[] = "exam_fees";

$result[] = array("name"=>"class 1", "type" => "class", "price" => 10 );
$result[] = array("name"=>"class 1", "type" => "class", "price" => 20 );
$result[] = array("name"=>"late fine", "type" => "late_fine", "price" => 50 );
$result[] = array("name"=>"late fine", "type" => "late_fine", "price" => 40 );

$i=0;
$x=0;
while($i < count($types)){
 while($x < count($result)){    
     if($types[$i] == $result[$x]['type']){          
        $data[$types[$i]]['name'] = $result[$x]['name'];
        $data[$types[$i]]['price'] += $result[$x]['price'];          
     }   
    $x++;
     }   
    $x = 0; 
    $i++;
 } 

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($data);
```

**Index array I talked about above in the text**

```
Array
  (
   [class] => Array
    (
        [name] => class 1
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 10
    )
   )
```

Result I am expecting without Notices

```
NOTICE Undefined index: price on line number 28
NOTICE Undefined index: price on line number 28

Array
(
   [class] => Array
    (
        [name] => class 1
        [price] => 30
    )

   [late_fine] => Array
    (
        [name] => late fine
        [price] => 90
    )
 )
```

Comment: You __cannot__ add a number to something that __is not defined__.

Comment: `$foo = 'bar';` doesn’t care if `$foo` already exists at that point or not, it will just be created if necessary. `$foo += 5;` however requires to _read_ the current value of the variable first - to know _what_ those 5 should be added to in the first place. Now this _reading_ can obviously not happen, if `$foo` doesn’t exist already.

Comment: hmm very straight and to the point answers. Thanks guys